# Passing an Object into a Class with ASP MVC. Newbie!

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am relatively new to asp and have this stupid problem which returns null all the time.  Here is my function which I think is pretty straightforward. I have been reading Steven Sanderson's book which has been extremely helpful. Anyway here is my function which I will explain afterwards

```
public ActionResult Menu(string page)
    {
        Func<Pages, NavLink> makeLink = parentPage => new NavLink
        {
            Text = parentPage.PageTitle ?? "Home",
            RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Pages",
                action = "List",
            }),
            IsSelected = (parentPage.PageTitle == page),
            IsFirst = (parentPage.PageOrder == 1)
        };

        List<NavLink> navlinks = new List<NavLink>();
        navlinks.Add(makeLink(null));

        foreach (var parent in pagesRepository.Pages.Where(x => x.PageParent == 0).OrderBy(x => x.PageOrder))
        {
                navlinks.Add(makeLink(parent));
        }

        return View(navlinks);
    }
```

The above function produces the following error **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

if I Pass a string instead of my Pages class, it works, however I need to access some of the properties of my Pages class in order to return essential values. The following function does not return an error

```
public ActionResult Menu(string page)
    {
        Func<string, NavLink> makeLink = parentPage => new NavLink
        {
            Text = parentPage ?? "Home",
            RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Pages",
                action = "List",
            }),
            IsSelected = (parentPage == page)
        };

        List<NavLink> navlinks = new List<NavLink>();
        navlinks.Add(makeLink(null));

        foreach (var parent in pagesRepository.Pages.Where(x => x.PageParent == 0).OrderBy(x => x.PageOrder))
        {
                navlinks.Add(makeLink(parent.PageTitle));
        }

        return View(navlinks);
    }
```

Thank you and your help will be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `null` when calling the function here:

```
navlinks.Add(makeLink(null));
```

So you must guard against this:

```
Func<Pages, NavLink> makeLink = parentPage => new NavLink
{
    Text = (parentPage != null) ? (parentPage.PageTitle ?? "Home") : "",
    RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new
    {
        controller = "Pages",
        action = "List",
    }),
    IsSelected = (parentPage != null) ? (parentPage.PageTitle == page) : false,
    IsFirst = (parentPage != null) ? (parentPage.PageOrder == 1) : 0
};
```

or simply never call it with null argument. So instead of:

```
List<NavLink> navlinks = new List<NavLink>();
navlinks.Add(makeLink(null));

foreach (var parent in pagesRepository.Pages.Where(x => x.PageParent == 0).OrderBy(x => x.PageOrder))
{
       navlinks.Add(makeLink(parent));
}

return View(navLinks);
```

You could simply:

```
var navlinks = pagesRepository
    .Pages
    .Where(x => x.PageParent == 0)
    .OrderBy(x => x.PageOrder)
    .Select(makeLink);
return View(navLinks);
```

Comment: Cant believe that error. You are a genius and testament to why I should never program late at night! Thanks Darin!